# Docx4j - Images in the document

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

How can we remove an image from the docx4j.

Say I have 10 images, and i want to replace 8 images with my own byte array/binary data, and I want to delete remaining 2.

I am also having trouble in locating images.

Is it somehow possible to replace text placeholders in the document with images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this post : http://vixmemon.blogspot.com/2013/04/docx4j-replace-text-placeholders-with.html

```
for(Object obj : elemetns){
   if(obj instanceof Tbl){
      Tbl table = (Tbl) obj;
         List rows = getAllElementFromObject(table, Tr.class);
            for(Object trObj : rows){
         Tr tr = (Tr) trObj;
         List cols = getAllElementFromObject(tr, Tc.class);
         for(Object tcObj : cols){
            Tc tc = (Tc) tcObj;
            List texts = getAllElementFromObject(tc, Text.class);
            for(Object textObj : texts){
              Text text = (Text) textObj;
                     if(text.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("${MY_PLACE_HOLDER}")){
                        File file = new File("C:\\image.jpeg");
                 P paragraphWithImage = addInlineImageToParagraph(createInlineImage(file));
                        tc.getContent().remove(0);

                        tc.getContent().add(paragraphWithImage);
              }
                  }
           System.out.println("here");
         }
           }
        System.out.println("here");
    }
}

wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("C:\\result.docx"));
```

Comment: offcourse its not perfet, i leave it to you to change it if you need similar solution someday..

Answer (score 1):

See [docx4j checking checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763778/docx4j-checking-checkboxes) for the 2 approaches to finding stuff (XPath, or non XPath traversal).

VariableReplace allows you to replace text placeholders, but not with images.  I think there may be code floating around (in the docx4j forums?) which extends it to do that.

But I'd suggest you use content control databinding instead.  See [how to create a new word from template with docx4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446805/how-to-create-a-new-word-from-template-with-docx4j)

You can use base64 encoded images in your XML data, and docx4j and/or Word will do the rest.