# set/unset checkbox value with docx4j in MS Word document

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

I'm trying to set/unset checkbox value with **docx4j** in MS Word document.

[image]

Using code from this post: [docx4j checking checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763778/docx4j-checking-checkboxes/15777578#comment47221771_15777578) I received following XML of this element from my document:

```
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:ns21="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint" xmlns:ns23="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:odx="http://opendope.org/xpaths" xmlns:odgm="http://opendope.org/SmartArt/DataHierarchy" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:ns17="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:odi="http://opendope.org/components" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ns32="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:ns30="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing" xmlns:ns31="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/compatibility" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:odq="http://opendope.org/questions" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:odc="http://opendope.org/conditions" xmlns:oda="http://opendope.org/answers">
<w:ffData>
    <w:name w:val=""/>
    <w:enabled/>
    <w:calcOnExit w:val="false"/>
    <w:checkBox>
        <w:sizeAuto/>
        <w:default w:val="true"/>
    </w:checkBox>
</w:ffData>
```

How could I unset value of this checkbox?

Thank You!

Comment: how you  insert checkbox in Ms word and xml is w:checkBox ? I haved inserted checkbox in MS word but the xml is <w:object w:dxaOrig="1440" w:dyaOrig="1440">
                    <v:shape type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:39.75pt;height:21.75pt" id="_x0000_i1049" o:ole="">
                        <v:imagedata o:title="" r:id="rId9"/>
                    </v:shape>
                    <w:control w:name="female" w:shapeid="_x0000_i1049" r:id="rId10"/>
                </w:object>

Answer (score 2):

You need to find your check box element, and when you have it the rest is trivial. Example.

```
for (Object o2 : contentControl.getSdtPr().getRPrOrAliasOrLock()) {

        Object o2Unwrapped = XmlUtils.unwrap(o2);
        if (o2Unwrapped  instanceof CTSdtCheckbox) {
            
            CTSdtCheckbox cTSdtCheckbox = (CTSdtCheckbox) o2Unwrapped;
            CTOnOff ctOnOff = new CTOnOff();

            ctOnOff.setVal("1");
            cTSdtCheckbox.setChecked(ctOnOff);
        }
}
```

Comment: There are two types of checkboxes. The question in referring to the legacy checkbox. This answer applies to the newer content control checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

In my work I had to write code to set/unset two kinds of checkboxes in MS Word documents (.docx): CTFFCheckBox and CTSdtCheckbox. I ended up using XPath and docx4j to find the checkboxes and change their values. Here is the sample code to flip all CTFFCheckBox in a document:

```
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(template);
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    List<Object> list = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w:checkBox",false);
    for (Object c : list) {
        JAXBElement<CTFFCheckBox> element = (JAXBElement<CTFFCheckBox>)c;
        CTFFCheckBox checkBox = element.getValue();
        BooleanDefaultTrue checkedVal = checkBox.getChecked();
        BooleanDefaultTrue defaultVal = checkBox.getDefault();
        if (checkedVal != null){
            checkedVal.setVal(!checkedVal.isVal());
        } else {
            defaultVal.setVal(!defaultVal.isVal());
        }
    }
```

To flip a CTSdtCheckbox I had to also modify the text symbol representing the checkbox. After locating the checkbox with one XPath expression I located the text symbol using another XPath expression relative to the checkbox:

```
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(template);
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    List<Object> list = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w14:checkbox", false);
    for (Object c : list) {
        JAXBElement<CTSdtCheckbox> element = (JAXBElement<CTSdtCheckbox>)c;
        CTSdtCheckbox checkbox = element.getValue();
        List<Object> list2 = mainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXPath("../..//w:t", element, false);
        Text chkSymbol = ((JAXBElement<Text>) list2.get(0)).getValue();
        CTOnOff checkedVal = checkbox.getChecked();
        if (checkedVal.getVal().compareTo("0") == 0) {
            checkedVal.setVal("1");
            chkSymbol.setValue(new String(Character.toChars(0x2612)));
        } else {
            checkedVal.setVal("0");
            chkSymbol.setValue(new String(Character.toChars(0x2610)));
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To unset the checkbox you either need to change the default flag or add a new child node `<w:checked w:val="false"/>` to the `<w:checkBox>` node.

E.g. for your example the XML for an *unchecked* checkbox (overriding the default value) would look like this:

```
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
<w:ffData>
    <w:name w:val=""/>
    <w:enabled/>
    <w:calcOnExit w:val="false"/>
    <w:checkBox>
        <w:sizeAuto/>
        <w:default w:val="true"/>
        <w:checked w:val="false"/>
    </w:checkBox>
</w:ffData>
```

With docx4j the code would look as follows:

```java
final CTFFCheckBox checkbox = // retrieve your checkbox
final BooleanDefaultTrue booleanFalse = new BooleanDefaultTrue();
booleanFalse.setVal(false);
checkbox.setChecked(booleanFalse); // alternatively call checkbox.setDefault(booleanFalse);
```

How to retrieve the `CTFFCheckBox` instance was already explained [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15777578/5207900) of your first question. If you have a `FldChar` instance you can retrieve the checkbox instance via `FldChar#getFfData()#getNameOrEnabledOrCalcOnExit()` which returns a list of `JAXBElement` elements. One of the `JAXBElement` elements has a `CTFFCheckbox` instance in its value (`JAXBElement#getValue`).